# How to provide an execution context to a future functor?

Tags: scala, future, functor, scala-cats

Using Cats, I have my functor declarations in a package object. This works fine, except for the `futureFunctor`, as it requires an implicit `ExecutionContext`:

```
package object util {

  implicit val futureFunctor: Functor[Future] = new Functor[Future] {
    //requires execution context:
    def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: A => B): Future[B] = fa map f
  }

  ...
}
```

Is there a way to implement `futureFunctor` such that it can acquire the execution context from the calling scope? I would hate to have to create a new implementation within each calling class instead of in the package. I am dependency-injecting my execution contexts into my classes, so just importing the global here isn't really practical. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
implicit def futureFunctor (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Functor[Future] = ...
```